# Get 1366x768 resolution for 15 inch laptop

Tags: resolution

I have a 15inch laptop with these resolutions available

[image: with these resolutions available].
Is there a way for me to alter it to allow 1366x768 resolution instead?

Comment: what OS? Might be able to show unsupported resolutions in many cases...

Comment: Your laptop screen is @ 16:10 ratio, while 1366x768 is a 16:9 ratio.  Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Please enter text as text. And why does your image have a scroll bar?

Comment: [This program](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU?page=1) looks like it will do what you need. It is going to be an ugly fight, and almost definately not worth the effort. But it may be possible. I have used a similar program (PowerStrip) back in the Windows XP days. It's not fun, but you can do things your monitor and graphics card manufacturers never intended.

Comment: Changing the resolution of a laptop screen to something other than the native resolution will severely impact the visual aesthetics - causing blurriness and stretched images. Why do you want to do this? There has to be a better answer.

Comment: OS is Windows. I have a script that uses image recognition to perform some tasks, and the image recognition data was  from a 1366x768 screen, so it'd only work well with the same resolution (resizing the window is not possible as it needs to be on full screen). The scroll bar in the image simply scrolls to other resolutions (that are higher than 2048x1536 or lower than 1280x768)